# Verify Text Present on a WebPage. Pass/ Fail

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify text on a webpage using Selemium Webdriver (java). I do not want the test to fail when the text is not present. I want to print Pass or Fail in the console. I dont want to verify the text from page source or assert it.

I tried to assert it by using the following statement and add an if else function: `assertTrue(Driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of text")).getText().matches("text to verify"));`

But it just completes or fails the test, I want the test to just give me a pass or fail result in the console and move on.

Comment: Well what's wrong with `System.out.println(...)`?????

Comment: when I use system.out.println() along with the mentioned statment its giving me a syntax error. @barak..do you know how to include the above statement with "if else" condition and print the result?

Comment: Well why don't you fix that error then?

Comment: I got it..adding the try catch function worked...Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code also:

```
    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("your text"))
        System.out.println("Text is present in the webpage");
    else
        System.err.println("Text is not present in the webpage");
```

**It will search for your text in the entire webpage and print 'Text is present in the webpage' if found, else it will print 'Text is not present in the webpage'.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add try catch block , so that when it thorws exception it will be catched and your execution will not stop, and in catch you can write pass or fail.